# Passing a child's state to parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component (Search) and I am trying to pass the states of lat & lng into the parent's state.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {

        lat: '',
        lng: ''
      };

      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();

        this.setState(
          {
            lat: addressObject.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: addressObject.geometry.location.lng(),
          }
        );

    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>

            <div className = 'search-box'>
            <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
              <input className = 'search-text'type = 'textbox' id="autocomplete" placeholder="Type your city"  
              />
              <button> submit</button>

            </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

and I am trying to alter the state of my parent's lat/lng state so that it equals to whatever the child's state is

```
class Display extends React.Component{
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
            lat: '{child's state}', ??
            lng: '{child's state}',??

        }
    }
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar />
                <WeatherDisplay 
                    data = {this.state}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How might I go about this? A follow-up question is, is this bad practice for react?

Comment: pass a function from parent to child, this function can be called by the child and will change the state in parent.

Comment: And yes, you must keep the lat/lng in this case only in one component: Either the parent or children

Comment: you should not post your google api key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in the parent component and pass it down to the child component as a prop. Like:

**Child Component:**

```
class Search extends React.Component {

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.props.update(
          {
            lat: addressObject.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: addressObject.geometry.location.lng(),
          }
        );

    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Script
              url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCnqBcICpcIUF4OcyIjqIEoIMXYOXqZnG8&libraries=places"
              onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad}
            />
            <div className = 'search-box'>
            <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
              <input className = 'search-text'type = 'textbox' id="autocomplete" placeholder="Type your city"  
              />
              <button> submit</button>

            </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }
```

**Parent Component:**

```
class Display extends React.Component{
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
            lat: null,
            lng: null

        }
    }
    update=({lat,lng})=>{
      this.setState({
        lat,
        lng
      })
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar update={this.update}/>
                <WeatherDisplay 
                    data = {this.state}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```